# Try, except clause with if, else

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, exception, python-3.7

Let's imagine this code:

```
    try:
        if condition1 and condition2: # some_exception may happen here
            function1()
        elif condition3 and condition4: # some_exception may happen here
            function2()
        else:
            big
            block
            of
            instructions
    except some_exception:
        big
        block
        of
        instructions
```

As you can see I repeat big block of instructions (both are same).
Is there a way to avoid repetition, but something different than putting the code in a function?

Some kind of different logic or using finally or else to try? I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: You could set a variable in your `else` and `except` clauses, and after the block, if the variable is set, call your `big block of instructions`.

Comment: Create a function from that big block and call it in the necessary places.

Comment: you could manually throw an exception in the `else` clause and only have to put the `big block` in the `except`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are averse to using a function, how about setting a variable in both places, and checking it later?

Something like this:

```
do_stuff = False
try:
    if condition1 and condition2: # some_exception may happen here
        function1()
    elif condition3 and condition4: # some_exception may happen here
        function2()
    else:
        do_stuff = True
except some_exception:
    do_stuff = True
    ...

if do_stuff:
    big
    block
    of
    instructions
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    if condition1 and condition2: # some_exception may happen here
        function1()
    elif condition3 and condition4: # some_exception may happen here
        function2()
    else:
         raise some_exception('This is the exception you expect to handle')
except some_exception:
    big
    block
    of
    instructions
```

What about this ?

Changed to raise as suggested by kaelwood